# Mistyped dates in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I was wondering if there is a way to detect mistyped dates in SQL in a general sense.

For example:

Order1 -  2014
Order2 - 2104
Order3 - 2041

I am guessing a form of case statement using wildcards would do the trick. But I am kind of a beginner in that regard.

EDIT - Sorry, for clarification, my column actually contains `YYYY-MM-DD`. However, I am only concerned with the year formatting. The datatype is `Date` for TSQL.

Thank you!

Comment: Have u tried " WHERE column_name_year SOUNDS LIKE '2014' "

Comment: Is that all you have is a year? Do you know what the datatype is? Are you only concerned with future dates?

Comment: Unfortunately, SOUNDS LIKE didn't work in my database. Also, in terms of present/future - Either one is ok. My goal is to learn more about SQL as I go, so learning one or the other would be excellent.

Comment: I would suggest doing the validation at the client... though I suspect you're doing this in SQL Server because you are **not** doing it at the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your data is already in a date column you don't need to worry about whether the value is a valid date or not.

So basically you are looking - from what I can tell - to see if the date falls in an expected range.

So you might want to do something like

```
SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE MYDATE NOT BETWEEN '01/01/1900' AND '12/31/2020'
```

*(obviously you can make the range whatever values you want, either static values or values stored in an options table)*

You could take this a step further and validate it on a dynamic range, something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM MYTABLE 
WHERE MYDATE NOT BETWEEN DATEADD(YEAR, -5, GETDATE()) AND DATEADD(YEAR, 5, GETDATE())
```

A further step would be to validate it in a range, based on some other field in the table, such as a created-on date for the record, like this:

```
SELECT T.* FROM MYTABLE T
WHERE T.MYDATE NOT BETWEEN DATEADD(YEAR, -5, T.CREATEDON) AND DATEADD(YEAR, 5, T.CREATEDON)
```

This gives you a bit more flexibility, because the "incorrect" dates may actually be valid at another point in time.

This should give you some starting points from which you can flesh out your exact needs.

Comment: `'01/01/1900' AND '12/31/2020'` very locale dependent formats there. Best use `YYYYMMDD` format, these are locale neutral.

Comment: @TT. Valid consideration to be aware of.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you are using a varchar field (through the comments) try,

```
Where your_column not like '200_' or your_column not like '201_'
```

if you were using a int for year you could use a range

```
Where your_column not between 2000 and 2014
```

Comment: This got me to a good start. I took your answer alongside eidylon's answer. Thank you!